# How to move text using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move the navigation bar to the top right. I tried to do it using padding. Padding-right,top,left works but padding-bottom doesn't work. I also tried using `float:right;` but it doesn't display in the exact position that I would like. What am i doing wrong?

```css
.nav1 a {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav1">
  <a href="./Index.html">HOME</a>
  <a href="./About_Me.html">ABOUT ME</a>
  <a href="./Contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you could provide more of the HTML  code, it would be easier to give you a good solution.

Comment: @Tasos.P Please accept an answer to close this question. (Hover to the left of the selected answer and a tick outline will appear. Click on the tick. ) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

search `flex` and `justify-content`

```css
.nav1 {
  background:aqua;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.nav1 a {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav1">
      <a href="./Index.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="./About_Me.html">ABOUT ME</a>
      <a href="./Contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
```

if you want a centered look.

```css
.nav1 {
  background:aqua;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  height:50px;
}

.nav1 a {
    padding-right: 10px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav1">
      <a href="./Index.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="./About_Me.html">ABOUT ME</a>
      <a href="./Contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by adding a `text-align` property to the `nav` css. 
See snippet:

```css
nav {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav1 a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav1">
  <a href="./Index.html">HOME</a>
  <a href="./About_Me.html">ABOUT ME</a>
  <a href="./Contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
```